# How do you get the remote to work on my Hauppage TV card?

Tags: 11.10, remote, mythbuntu, lirc

I've installed Mythbuntu and during the install I selected my hauppauge tv card and the remote doesn't work.  Now what do I do?

I see a .lircrc file in my home dir but ps -ef|grep lirc yields nothing.  I've read on other posts that the kernel is now handling this but I don't know what to try.  irw isn't installed.

How does a program get signals from the remote without lirc installed?  Where are the config files I need to look at?  How can I debug this?

Comment: Which model of TV card is it? Most of the newer ones implement the remote input as an input device (like an extra keyboard). My setup (which is quite old now) takes a hybrid approach - I use the raw key impulses the remote generates by default, and also run lircd in "evdev" mode (which uses input devices instead of IR pulses) to route commands to programs like mplayer. Step 1 : does pushing the "OK" button on the remote cause an "enter" impulse in the current terminal?

Comment: No.  Nothing happens no matter which keys I press on the remote.

Comment: Try `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` and pushing all the buttons again to see what gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, with my Nova-T usb tv stick and remote I install lirc, `sudo apt-get install lirc`  and choose my usb tv stick and when choosing the remote it doesn't really show me it listed, so I just choose anything.  I stop the lirc service, `sudo service lirc stop`  and run `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` which gives me

`I: Bus=0003 Vendor=2040 Product=7070 Version=0100

N: Name="IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver"

P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/ir0

S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/rc/rc0/input14

U: Uniq=

H: Handlers=kbd event14`

I then edit /etc/lirc/hardware.conf and change `REMOTE_DEVICE=` to `REMOTE_DEVICE="/dev/input/event14"`  to match my remotes event id, then restart lirc,  `sudo service lirc start`

Hope this helps somewhat.