# Tracing IR to Hauppage remote on Mythbuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mythbuntu, remote-control, lirc

I have installed Mythbuntu 12.04 on an AMD dual core.

Basic TV play and record functions are working, but I am having some troubles with the remote. The card is a Hauppauge WinTV-HVR 1250.

I have looked at [How do you get the remote to work on my Hauppage TV card?](https://askubuntu.com/q/97713/80258). In the Mythbuntu control centre, I went the Infrared and changed the remote to Hauppage HVR-1100. It didn't seem to work, so I tried regular stuff like checking the voltage on the batteries (1.5V) and making sure the IR cable was plugged in the right place.

I stopped lirc with `sudo service lirc stop`. It failed because it could not find /sys/class/rc/*/.

I tried `ls /dev/l*` but there was no lirc0 or lirc1.

I ran `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` to find input devices, but nothing in the list looks like an IR-receiver.

I looked at /etc/lirc/hardware.conf. Here are some of the important lines:

```
REMOTE="Hauppauge HVR-1100"
REMOTE_DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
REMOTE_LIRCD_CONF="hauppauge/lircd.conf/hauppauge"
```

I tried pressing several keys on the Hauppauge remote and then looking at the tail of /var/log/kern.log, but no keystrokes seem to be coming through.

Can you help me trace the IR signal? I don't actually have confidence that anything is coming through.

Comment: I think I'm having a similar problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190392/mythbuntu-12-lirc-device-doesnt-appear-to-even-exist Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Just spent a little while trying to have Mythremote (iOS) talk to the network interface. I made sure in the Mythbuntu setup that the network interface was turned on and that it was set to the standard port. I also had Mythremote talk to that IP address and port. No Joy. Mythremote says "The connection has failed".