# mythbuntu 12 - lirc device doesn't appear to even exist

Tags: input-devices, mythbuntu, devices, lirc

I'm trying to get a new installation of Mythbuntu working. So far, everything is OK except the remote. The sensor for the remote is on my Hauppauge WinTV HVR 1250.

First I tried to run `irw` to see what was being picked up by the sensor:

```
$ irw 
connect: No such file or directory
```

Then trying to run lircd gives:

```
$ lircd start$ lircd start
lircd: can't open or create /var/run/lirc/lircd.pid
```

I look for any `lirc` devices and find there are none:

```
$ ls /dev/li*
ls: cannot access /dev/li*: No such file or directory
```

Just to be sure, I check in `/proc/bus/input/devices`, which shows me two powerbuttons (not sure why), kbd and mouse dev, and the audio devs. Nothing for the IR receiver on the tuner card (which I thought was strange because shouldn't the tuner show up here?).

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=099a Product=7202 Version=0111
N: Name="Wireless Keyboard/Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:10.1-2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb8/8-2/8-2:1.0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=099a Product=7202 Version=0111
N: Name="Wireless Keyboard/Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:10.1-2/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb8/8-2/8-2:1.1/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd mouse0 event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=4837fff072ff32d bf54444600000000 70001 20c100b17c000 267bfad9415fed 9e168000004400 10000002
B: REL=143
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Line"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=2000

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Front Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Line-Out"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=40
```

According to `dmesg`, the driver was registered, but it doesn't look like any devices was associated with the driver:

```
$ dmesg | grep irc
[   10.631162] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 249
```

So far, I've seen a number of forum pages suggesting that I use some trick to create a link between `/dev/lirc` and some other device that is the REAL IR sensor, like `/dev/event5`, but those cases assume that the real device is shown from `/proc/bus/input/devices`, and I don't see any such device there.

Any suggestions on how to fix or further diagnose this?

FWIW, it seems like this question describes a similar problem, but has no solution yet:

[Tracing IR to Hauppage remote on Mythbuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178356/tracing-ir-to-hauppage-remote-on-mythbuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

**lirc** isn't running because you are trying to start it as a regular user instead of root. That is why there are no **lirc** devices. **irw** needs to be run after **lirc** has been started, you will only get **irw** to show responses from the remote if **lirc** has been successfully started.

You need to start **lirc** as root, e.g.

```
sudo lircd start
```

Though I always use

```
sudo service lirc start
```